# ¿Como continuar la ejecución o devolver error desde una función anidada?

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring

Buenas.

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
<?php

class ControladorDeEjemplo extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreData $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        /*
        bloque de
        instrucciones
        bastante extenso 1
         */

        if ($condicionDeError) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Descripcion del error']);
        }

        /*
        bloque de
        instrucciones
        bastante extenso 2
         */

        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }
}
```

y quiero sacar el bloque de instrucciones a otra función, ya que el método original que quiero arreglar tiene mas de 120 lineas de extensión. Entonces quiero hacer algo como esto:

```
<?php

class ControladorDeEjemplo extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreData $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();

        funcion($data);

        /*
        bloque de
        instrucciones
        bastante extenso 1
         */

        return response()->json(['success' => true]);
    }

    public public function Funcion($datos)
    {
        /*
        bloque de
        instrucciones
        bastante extenso 2
         */

        $variable1;
        $variable2;

        if ($condicionDeError) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => 'Descripcion del error']);
        }
    }
}
```

Pero algunos problemas que tengo son:

- El primer bloque de instrucciones consulta a la base de datos y asigna las variables necesarias para que el `/* bloque de instrucciones bastante extenso 2 */` funcione (que en este ejemplo serían las `$variable1` y `$variable2`)
- Si no se usa `return` cuando se llama a la función `Funcion()` dentro de `store()`, no devuelve el error, pero si se usa, no continúa la rutina hasta el final, a pesar de que estén correctas las condiciones.

Esto se puede arreglar con una condición de esta forma. (esta es una idea)

```
<?php
if(get_class($result = funcion()) == "Response"){
    return $result;
}
```

Pero no tengo forma de pasar los resultados de la función al contexto anterior de "store" sin convertirlas en variables de la clase.

Otra idea es usar excepciones y devolver los datos como arreglos. Como lo indica [http-exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors#http-exceptions). Pero esto implica modificar el código que interpreta la salida en javascript.

Me gustaría saber si existe una forma de hacer esto elegantemente :P

Comment: Leí la pregunta varias veces y no me quedan claras varias cosas, por no decir que la mayoría: ¿a qué return te refieres en el segundo problema? ¿en dónde se utilizarían `$variable1` y `$variable2`? ¿algún motivo para incluir más de 120 líneas en un método de un controlador?

Comment: @Shaz ese es el problema, el método está como si fuera programación estructurada y sin funciones adicionales. los datos que se envían al controlador incluyen 2 arreglos, esto produce que se deban ingresar 3 arreglos en tres tablas distintas de la BD, este es el motivo de la extensión del método :P y el motivo de la pregunta.. debo separar el método `store` para hacerlo mas comprensible.

Comment: La verdad me parece que una respuesta se basaría más en opiniones, pues aunque hay un problema, veo muchas formas posibles de solucionarlo, yo simplemente enviaría esas 120 líneas a un servicio, no debería ser responsabilidad del controlador manejar tanta lógica, las haría  PSR-2 y jugaría con el resto de parámetros de entrada y salida en la función store().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tú no manejarías las excepciones en el frontend sino directamente en PHP. 
Por lo que leo, entiendo que $variable1 y $variable2 se generan en `Funcion` y necesitas retornarlas. En ese caso sería

```
<?php

class RepoSubjectCourseController extends Controller
{
    public function store(StoreData $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        try { 
          list($variable1,$variable2)=$this->Funcion($data);
          // código que utiliza $variable1 y $variable2
          return response()->json(['success' => true]);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
          return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }

    }

    public function Funcion($datos)
    {
        /*
        bloque de
        instrucciones
        bastante extenso
         */

        $variable1;
        $variable2;

        return [$variable1,$variable2];
    }
}
```

Si la operación que realizas en Funcion no tira una excepción nativamente, entonces puedes añadir, previo al return:

```
if ($condicionDeError) {
  throw new Exception('Ha ocurrido un error');  
}
```

Y con eso gatillarías el catch de tu función store.

Comment: Así lo he dejado, no he encontrado una forma más rápida de hacerlo :P `try { $arreglo = ControladorDeEjemplo::Funcion($data); } catch (Exception $e) { return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $e->getMessage()]); }`